# Database proj in VS2010 doesn't load when Resharper Ultimate 2016.1.2 installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I have a solution in vs2010 which includes a database project.  When I added Resharper Ultimate 2016.1.2, this project won't load stating that Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.Sql100DatabaseSchemaProvider cannot be loaded.  This is a dbproj excerpt:

```html
<DSP>Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.Sql100DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
```

I've read other answers that say to change to "Sql110" and "v11.0" for upgrades from vs2010 to vs 2012 but this doesn't work in my case.

Without Resharper, it loads fine.  How can I get this project to load with Resharper Ultimate installed?

thanks!

Comment: Please [file an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=) with as much detail as possible, ideally with the problem solution, if you can (you can always mark the issue, or attachments as only visible to "JetBrains team" to keep them private).

Comment: Visual Studio log might be a bit more informative (thru running `devenv.exe /Log filename`), but only on the first VS start after installing any extension (doing Repair of R# install would do).

Comment: Also any first-chance exceptions when trying to load the project (e.g. attaching to VS with another VS as a debugger, with Break on All Exceptions for managed exceptions).

Comment: I have checked this type of projects at my machine - it works fine. It must be something special about your setup.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 can run with .NET Framework v4.0 without any newer frameworks, and R# still supports such systems, but as most of them out there actually got v4.5+ this is not a thoroughly-tested scenario. Installing the latest .NET Framework *might* improve VS 2010 experience with R#.